Sentry not logging errors for some clients in React app
I'm experiencing an issue where Sentry is not logging errors for a specific client in my React app. I have confirmed that the client does not have any ad blockers installed and is not using Brave. When I reproduced the steps to encounter the error, Sentry logged the errors correctly for me. How can I troubleshoot this?
Here is the Sentry configuration:
if (import.meta.env.VITE_ENABLE_SENTRY === 'true') {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations: [
      Sentry.browserTracingIntegration(),
      Sentry.replayIntegration({
        maskAllText: true,
        blockAllMedia: true,
      }),
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    environment: import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT,

    replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 0.1,
    denyUrls: ['pagesense.io', 'zohocdn.com'],
  })
}

and the versions React and Sentry respectively:
"@types/react": "^17.0.39",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
"@sentry/vite-plugin": "^2.14.2",
"@sentry/react": "^7.103.0",
"@sentry/tracing": "^7.103.0",

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What does the browser devtools say for the client? Are there any blocked requests to Sentry's ingest domain? Are there even any sent events to Sentry?

Unfortunately I do not have direct access to the client's devtools or their network requests at the time the issue occurred. Also that particular error has been patched as that was critical.
